# How to trigger an iframe event Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have an IFRAME and I want to trigger an event (which is inside the iframe) from the parent of an IFRAME:

**Just a rough example** of what I am trying to do :

```
<iframe id="i">
  <div id="test"></div>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {  // Event is binded inside the iframe 

   $("#test").live({ click : function() { alert("hello"); } });
  });
  </script>
</iframe>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() { // Want to trigger it from outside the iframe
 $("#i").contents().find("#test").trigger("click");
});
</script>
```

Comment: you can't write your code inside iframe tag

Comment: @Somebodyisintrouble Please notice `JUST A ROUGH EXAMPLE` in my question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your jquery is correct only problem is that that you are doing this when document is ready but at that time iframe is not getting fully loaded therefore div doesn't exist at that time and not triggers click.
Change your main page script to

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //want to trigger it from outside the iframe
    $("#i").load(function(){
        $("#i").contents().find("div").trigger("click");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

[ger javascript event from within an iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8319613/trigger-javascript-event-from-within-an-iframe)

but look at answer from Gilly

```
document.myFrameName.myFunction();
```

regards

Comment: but it will not trigger click