# JQuery Content Click Not working

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have a class inside an iframe. I am able to change the color of this class using the following jquery code:

```
$("#chart_iframe0").contents().find(".btn-green").css("background","#BADA55");
```

This is working fine.

I now what to click on it with jquery so I'm using this code:
However, now i want to perform the same action using "click" event of jquery:

```
$("#chart_iframe0").contents().find(".btn-green").click();
```

But this is not working as I want.
Can anyone guide me what's wrong with the second jquery code ? Is it related to the syntax or something else?

Here is the html area of it:

```
<div id="btn-actions" class="tclass">
<a class="btn btn-wide btn-green">
<span style="">Click me</span>
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please post page HTML here...

Comment: Can you setup a jsfiddle?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10943727/how-to-trigger-an-iframe-event-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Try using .on() to bind the click event to the element.

```
$("#chart_iframe0").contents().find(".btn-green").on( "click", function(){
    alert('test');
});
```